# ios crashlytics: where are the CLS_LOGs available

Tags: ios, logging, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Basically I want to get NSLog output from remote testers. What is being suggested is that I should use Flurry, Crashlytics, etc. I get crash reports from Crashlytics but I want NSLog/CLS_Log output shown somewhere even without any crash. Can crashlytics show logs even without crashes ? I am not seeing any logs in dashboard.

Is there any other tool to view NSLog remotely?

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

Currently, we only display the logs when there is a crash on iOS. Will let the team know you'd like to see this as an option though.

Comment: Yes that will be a great addition. For now, found that loggly just solves this issue but would love if Fabric supports it!!

Comment: Bugfender is a great option for remote logging.